# How to provide to Spinnaker application already existing in cluster namespaces and its resources?

Tags: deployment, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Env: `on-prem k8s v1.28.3`
Spinnaker: `v1.33.0`
Spinnaker-operator: `v1.3.1`
Halyard: `image: armory/halyard:operator-a6ac1d4`

I've deployed Spinnaker CD to our On-Prem Kubernetes cluster via spinnaker-operator, and set it up a little, but here is the problem:

If you're deploying Spinnaker to already existing cluster, you might see automatically created applications. Docs says to ignore them, creating new ones insted, as I did.

But created application is absolutely empty. I know that I can create a pipeline, and created by it resources will be seen in here, but this not exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a project, let's name it `learning`. And I have many resources in k8s, that belongs to our `learning` project, such as `namespaces`, `ingresses`, `deployments` etc.

I want to create an application in Spinnaker, let's name it `learning-apps`, and group all existing resources associated with it into this application,
like namespaces `learning-01`,`learning-02`,`ingress-learning`, and everything inside of them to make it visible in my app.

However, Spinnaker do not provide such an option in UI, and I didn't find any information how to configure it anywhere else.

Is there a possibility to configure somewhere my new application, add namespaces to it, and will it see and group resources within this namespace the way, as it doing to already existing ones?

Beautiful, cool and cute generated and grouped automatically application:
[image: Get from existing cluster]

Ugly, empty, and idk how to configure created new one:
[image: huh]

There is no option to add anything in config:
[image: nothing to update here]

And, finally, `+ Create Server Group` provides only manifest-based setting, nothing more:
[image: n-o-t-h-i-n-g]

So, is there a way to add namespaces to this app? To add its resources? Anything?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You used the kubernetes flag which, if you read the description, says "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."

Comment: "If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK." - Thanks for correcting me, but it seems that my situation fits this description, because the problem is somewhere in the configuration that is sent to the pod and is perceived by it. Could you suggest me tags that suits more for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinnaker uses annotations and labels to the resources that are deployed.
If you want to add already existing in cluster resource to Spinnaker Application, you have to annotate it manually. Or, you can use the same manifests to "deploy it again" via pipeline. It will label and annotate all resources that will be created by those manifests, and they will appear in Spinnaker UI.

Note: Namespaces are not shown in the list.
Services will appear in LOADBALANCERS menu.
Pods will appear too, according to deployment.
To reproduce:
Deploy `nginx-demo` using Spinnaker pipelines, and then use `kubectl describe all -n <>` to see how it's labeled/annotated.

Thx for `-1`